# Dealing with partial views and javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have set up a partial view to render in an index page. The partial view gets posted using Ajax to the server when a user clicks a sort button. This is so the entire page won't refresh just the partial view table.

The problem is after the first sort, the JavaScript in the index page is no longer effective. I worked around this by putting the js in the partial view itself to persist the events, but this produces js errors to saying 'continue' or 'ignore'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your newly injected elements ( via ajax) is not aware of the events bounded. So those event bindings are not availabel to them.

You should change your event bindings to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) so that it handles the current elements and future elements (added to DOM dynamically via ajax or so)

for example, if you want to handle the ***click*** event for elements with css class `someCssClassSelector`,

Change

```
$(".someCssClassSelector").click(function(){
  //do something
});
```

to

```
$(document).on("click",".someCssClassSelector",function(){
  //do something
});
```

Comment: that works, what if I need to persist a 'scroll' event is that possible, that's the other feature that needs to persist. I will update the question.

Comment: @RayEatmon: Do not update the question. Post as a new question with relevant details